# i can't copy xml file from assest

Tags: android

i want to copy xml file in data directory..i did this but the below  code can't copy xml file in data directory.

```
private void copyAsset(){

    AssetManager assetmanager=getAssets();

    InputStream in=null;



    OutputStream out=null;
    String filename="deathtrack.xml";
    try {
        in=assetmanager.open(filename);
        out=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory().toString()+"/" +filename);
        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log. e ( "tag" , "Failed to copy asset file: " , e);
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8" ));


    int n;
    while ((n= reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
```

if anyone knows  this how to do ?please help me.

Comment: What problem are you running into?  Do you get an error in the logs or are you getting an IOException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you use 
Writer writer = new StringWriter();

copyFile function is simple:

```
     private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int read;
         while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
           out.write(buffer, 0, read);
         }
     }
```